# How to solve this system of nonlinear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

How to solve these equations for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $x$?

I have the following:

\begin{align}
1 &=  2a+b+c\\
a &= (a+b)x + 0.25(a+c)\\
a&=(a+c)(1-x)\\
b&=a(1-x)+c(x-0.25)\\
c&=b(1-x)+a(x-0.25)
\end{align}

I tried, but ended circular at the point I started. Can someone help me?

Comment: I plugged these into WolframAlpha and the answer isn't particularly pretty, have you written the equations down correctly?

Comment: Yes, these are the equations I arrived at, while solving for a stationary distribution.

Comment: Hi, after solving first three equations we get, x = 3/4 * (a+c). Not sure after this, how to proceed.

Comment: If it is any help, by multiplying the equation from your last comment by $x$ again you get $x^2=\frac34(a+c)x=\frac34c$.

Comment: How did you get $0.75*c$? We have $x^2= 0.75 * (a+c)* x $. Then? I am ending at $0.75^2*(a+c)^2$...

Comment: I have used $(a+c)x=c$, which we have from the third equation. (BTW if you want me to receive notification of your comment, you need to [ping me](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ah, ok, got it. Let me try with this new information.

Comment: @FanofGrothendieck It worked (I have received the notification about your comment.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we simplify the second equation we get $$(a+b)x=\frac34a-\frac{c}4.\tag{A}$$
If we simplify the third equation, we get $$(a+c)x=c.\tag{B}$$
Now we can simply add these two equations together and use
$(2a+b+c)x=x$ on the LHS to get
$$x=\frac{3a+3c}4.\tag{C}$$
If we multiply this equation by $x$ again, we get
$$x^2=\frac34(a+c)x\overset{(B)}=\frac34c,$$
i.e.,
$$c=\frac43x^2$$
So we managed to express $c$ in terms of $x$.

From (C) we have $a+c=\frac43x$. Using this we can get $a=\frac43x-c$, i.e., 
$$a=\frac43x-\frac43x^2=\frac43x(1-x).$$

From $2a+b+c=1$ we have $b=1-2a-c$ which leads to
$$b=1-\frac83x+\frac43x^2.$$

It is relatively easy to check (simply by plugging the values into the equations) that these equations fulfill $2a+b+c=1$ and also (A) and (B). This means that the first three equations are fulfilled for any $x$.

Now it remains to check the fourth and the fifth equation. Unless I have made a mistake when transcribing the equations to WolframAlpha, both equations lead to the cubic equation
$$8x^3-13x^2+12x-3=0.$$
See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%2F3*x*%281-x%29*%281-x%29%2B4%2F3*x%5E2*%28x-1%2F4%29-%281-8%2F3*x%2B4%2F3*x%5E2%29) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-8%2F3*x%2B4%2F3*x%5E2%29*%281-x%29%2B4%2F3*x*%281-x%29*%28x-1%2F4%29-4%2F3*x%5E2).

This equation seems to have [no rational roots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8x%5E3-13x%5E2%2B12x-3%3D0). (At least Wolfram Alpha did not return any. This can be checked manually using [rational roots test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), although this can be a lot of work.)

So the best way is probably to try it solve numerically. There are also exact methods to find roots of [cubic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function), but they tend to be too laborious to be done by hand, unless the coefficients and roots are "nice".

Answer (score 1):

Using Grobner basis in maxima gives:

grobner_basis([2*a+b+c-1,(a+b)*x+(a+c)/4-a,(a+c)*(1-x)-a,a*(1-x)+c*(x-1/4)-b,b*(1-x)+a*(x-1/4)-c]);

(- 44) x + (- 144) a^2  + 213 a + (- 36),

(- 11) c + (- 48) a^2  + 60 a + (- 12),

(- 11) b + 48 a^2  + (- 82) a + 23,

(- 144) a^3  + 381 a^2  + (- 312) a + 64

The last equation is a cubic in "a" alone.

The second last solves for b given a.

The third last solves for c in a.

The top equation solves for x in a.

Grobner Basis and Buchberger's algorithm explain how this works.

regards arthur

---

lower case x

grobner_basis([2*A+B+C-1,(A+B)*x+(A+C)/4-A,(A+C)*(1-x)-A,A*(1-x)+C*(x-1/4)-B,B*(1-x)+A*(x-1/4)-C]);

(- 3) C + 4 x^2 ,

(- 3) B + 4 x^2  + (- 8) x + 3,

(- 3) A + (- 4) x^2 + 4 x,

(- 8) x^3  + 13 x^2  + (- 12) x + 3

Comment: Thank you. This is a new method I am learning today.